# Arduino Pro Mini bootloader issue

Tags: arduino, bootloader, arduino-ide

I have uploaded a project on an Arduino Pro Mini for an LED matrix. The Arduino Pro Mini has a problem after upload. The LED flashes fast and I cannot upload anything else like a blink sketch. The Arduino IDE gives this communication error:

> avrdude: stk500_getsync(): not in sync: resp=0x00

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you solved your problem, but I just found it while looking for another answer.

Usually that issue means that avrdude can't talk to the programmer, which means that either:

- you did not select the right programmer/board in the `tools` menu,
- you did not select the right USB port,
- you did not install the FTDI driver if you're using a FTDI based programmer,
- your USB device has not been brought up by your system (then you shall try replugging the cable, reload the USB driver or rebooting your computer, depending on your OS and setup)

HTH